# Exporting atollic project as makefile based project

Tags: eclipse, makefile, ide, embedded

I am currently building my embedded system project using build button on atolic truestudio. 
Is it possible to export this as makefile project which can be build using make command line.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You have to open properties of your project then **C/C++ Build** -> **Tool Chain Editor** -> **Current builder** switch this to **GNU Make Builder** then rebuild your project and check Debug/Release folder where makefiles will be generated and you can build it from console :)